# Grails 4 Audit Logging w/ Spring Security does not record "Actor"

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, audit-logging

I'm using Spring Security Rest and the Grails Audit Logging plugin.  Audit log records are being created with all the correct information except the `actor` property is always saved with the `defaultActor` value.

Below is my configuration. Does anyone have any ideas? What should I be looking for?  Thanks in advance for your time.

#### build.gradle

```
ext.springSecurityRestVersion = '3.0.0.RC1'
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:${springSecurityRestVersion}"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest-gorm:${springSecurityRestVersion}"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:audit-logging:4.0.3'
    ...
}
```

#### application.yml

```
grails.plugin.auditLog:
  auditDomainClassName: "us.mycompany.api.AuditLogEvent"
  logFullClassName: false
  defaultActor: "mycompany"

grails.plugin.springsecurity:
  userLookup.userDomainClassName: 'us.mycompany.api.Person'
  userLookup.authorityJoinClassName: 'us.mycompany.api.PersonRole'
  authority.className: 'us.mycompany.api.Role'
  filterChain.chainMap:
    #Stateless chain
    - { pattern: '/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter' }
  rest.token:
    storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName: 'us.mycompany.api.AuthenticationToken'
    validation:
      useBearerToken: false
      enableAnonymousAccess: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I debugged this, it seems like the `springSecurityService` dependency in `SpringSecurityRequestResolver` was null, so I had to explicitly wire `SpringSecurityRequestResolver` in `resources.groovy`.

I know that I shouldn't have to do that, but it did fix my problem, so this is at least a workaround.

#### resources.groovy

```
import grails.plugins.orm.auditable.resolvers.SpringSecurityRequestResolver

beans = {
    auditRequestResolver(SpringSecurityRequestResolver) {
        springSecurityService = ref('springSecurityService')
    }
}
```